# how Disable url rewrite for localhost

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to access magneto root in localhost using **localhost/new-web** but it is redirecting me to the **localhost/new-web/localhost/new web**.

In magento database in core_config_table i have made changes in base unsecure url to http://localhost/new-web

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to adjust RewriteBase in .htaccess. If you have "http://localhost/new-web" set in your core_config_data (web/unsecure/base_url, web/secure/base_url), make sure it's not active.

Look out for this section:

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

 #RewriteBase /
```

Make sure, the RewriteBase line is a comment.

Next, delete all contents from the cache by removing anything from /var/cache/

Second, if this won't help, try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I run all my local installations directly on ip addresses instead of hostnames and seldomly run into problems with it.